# How do I load two models in one JSON request in Ember-data?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-data

Using Ember-data and Ember.js, I'm trying to load two models with one JSON request. The models have a relationship analogous to this:

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
    name:  DS.attr('string'),
    dogs:  DS.hasMany('App.Dog'),
});

App.Dog = DS.Model.extend({
    name:  DS.attr('string'),
    owner: DS.belongsTo('App.Person'),
});
```

My server is sending JSON like this:

```
{
    "dog": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Fido",
        "owner": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "John Smith",
            "dogs": [1]
        }
    }
}
```

…And yet, Ember-data still sends a request (using findQuery) to my server trying to get the owner JSON.

I have a jsFiddle set up that demonstrates it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6kQ8s/2/). To watch the problem happen, you'll need to go to this link to activate the route/template:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/6kQ8s/2/show/#/dog/1

I haven't defined findQuery() in my adapter on purpose because I shouldn't need that to get data that I have already sent… Right?

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm doing the following (using ember-data revision 8)

```
App.Dog = DS.Model.extend({
    name:  DS.attr('string'),
    owner: DS.belongsTo('App.Person', { embedded: true }),
});
```

Additionally, I have to tell the serializer to load a mapping for this relation.
Though it's not required, I'm using my own DS.Serializer subclass. At initialisation
time the serializer loads a mapping for the Person class, which specifies that
embedded relationships should be loaded.

```
  App.WOSerializer = DS.Serializer.extend({
    init: function(){
      this._super();
      this.map(App.Dog, {
        person: {
          embedded: 'load'
        }
      });
  });
```

*Edit by question asker:*

The serializer needed to be initialized in the adapter.

```
App.adapter = DS.Adapter.create({
    // ...
    serializer: App.WOSerializer.create()
});
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate that this works by editing [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kbWrG/8/) jsFiddle? (It has the latest versions of all the libraries) I was unable to get it to work even after specifying the serializer for the adapter.

Comment: Alright, but first supply an example that's working, except for the relationship. What I mean is the current example does not even show the dog name. Don't forget to use Capitalised class names (e.g. App.Adapter instead of App.adapter). So if you make an example that at least manages to show the Dog name then I'll add the code for showing the owner name too.

Comment: Hi, I just tried your new fiddle, but I still do not see the dog's name appear in the result pane. I tried on FireFox, Chrome and Safari on Mac. Ignore my previous remark about capitalised class names. Though it's true it doesn't apply to the App.adapter in your example as that is not a class, but an object. I had missed the 'create', thought I read 'extend'.

Comment: Even when going to this link? http://fiddle.jshell.net/AwgXg/show/#/dog/1 After every change you have to update the Fiddle and go to the URL that activates the route/template, it's pretty annoying but the only way to do it ATM. Just tried it on Firefox and Chrome for OS X and Linux, shows the dog's name in all cases.

Comment: OK, thanks. I have now adapted your example to show the related object. You can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/olmeca/AwgXg/19/).

Answer (score 0):

Try use `embedded` property.

```
App.Dog = DS.Model.extend({
    name:  DS.attr('string'),
    owner: DS.belongsTo('App.Person', { embedded: true }),
});
```

Comment: I tried this before asking this, I'm afraid it doesn't work. Can you please try out and demonstrate your solutions using the jsFiddle I provided?

Comment: @DavisSorenson, I think that my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479842/ember-data-rendering-hasmany is same as your. I have the same problems there.