# Ember Data not mapping relations with Padrino API

Tags: javascript, ruby, sinatra, ember.js, ember-data

This is driving me nuts. I have a simple data model set up (using Padrino); I'm long past the stage of actually getting any error messages but adding 'App.Repo' models to an 'App.Stack' model just…doesn't work.

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 10
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({
    bulkCommits: false,
    mappings: {
      stars: App.Stars,
      stacks: App.Stacks
    }
  })
});

App.Stack = DS.Model.extend({
  url: DS.attr('string'),
  repos: DS.hasMany('App.Repo')
});

App.Repo = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  url: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  language: DS.attr('string'),
  watchers: DS.attr('number'),
  stack: DS.belongsTo('App.Stack'),
  stackId: DS.attr('number')
});
```

---

```
var store = App.get('router.store');
newStack = store.createRecord(App.Stack);
console.log(newStack.serialize())
-> Object {url: null}    // no mention of a repos array like I was expecting?
newStack.set('url', 'http://google.com');
console.log(newStack.serialize());
-> Object {url: "http://google.com"}    // this works though


var repo = App.Repo.find().objectAt(0);
console.log(repo.serialize());
-> Object {name: "floere/james", url: "https://github.com/floere/james", description: "Voice commanded servant for OSX", language: "Ruby", watchers: 97…}
// so this exists too…

repos = newStack.get('repos');
repos.pushObject(repo);
newStack.get('repos.length'); // 1 (repos.toArray() etc etc all work too)

// but then…
console.log(newStack.serialize())
-> Object {url: null}

// and so then I try to save the relationship on the server anyway…
store.commit()
=> {"stack"=>{"url"=>nil}} // in my Ruby server logos
```

The store is all set up fine talking to my back end (for example submitting a POST to /repo.json sends the correct request); it just doesn't recognise that App.Stack has any relation.

No idea what's going wrong or what to look at for help :(

### Also

I tried making the relations in my Ruby console and then accessing them in a view. This is what happens

```
// in the router
router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('body', 'stacks', router.get('store').findAll(App.Stack));
// in the view
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="stacks">
{{#each stack in controller }}
  {{stack.id}} // this works
  {{stack.url}} // this works
  {{stack.repos.length}} // this returns the correct count
  {{#each repo in stack.repos}}
    // this loops the right number of times. so there *is* something there. somehow.
    {{repo}} // prints out <App.Repo:ember490>
    {{repo.id}} // prints out [object Object]
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

On that last note - maybe a clue in the [object Object]?

I'm so lost :(

### More Info:

I'm using Padrino with Mongoid, using RABL to give me JSON. As I said, I can query for & template out my Stack & Repo records. Here's a JSON sample for the /stacks.json endpoint

```
{
"stacks": [
    {
        "account_id": null, 
        "id": "50c127ff6f094144ed000001", 
        "stars": [
            {
                "description": "Voice commanded servant for OSX", 
                "id": "50c128996f0941cfe8000001", 
                "name": "floere/james"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing you're using `DS.Serializer`. Out of box, this doesn't serialize relationships. Use `DS.REStSerializer` or at least look at the `addBelongsTo` function to see how to serialize relationships!

Comment: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/serializer.js#L303

Comment: My bad - left out that bit; updating it in the code now - I'm using DS.RESTAdapter (which implements DS.RESTSerializer)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to add hasMany relationships to your json object manually by looping through the `repos` array. I'm doing this in my adapter's `createRecord` method.

```
createRecord: (store, type, record) ->
  data = {}
  data[root] = @toData(record, { includeId: true })

  repos = []
  stack.get("repos").forEach (repo) ->
    repos.pushObject repo.serialize()

  data[root]["repos"] = repos

  ...
```

Comment: sorry for the coffeescript when the question was in javascript. was answering this in a hurry.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to get embedded related objects in the JSON to load properly. Basically you have to subclass the serializer and then in its initializer you tell it to register a map for the relationship. Here's an example for a model class called Category that has a to-many relationship 'resourceTypes':

```
App.WOSerializer = DS.Serializer.extend({
   init: function(){
     this._super();
     this.map(App.Category, {
       resourceTypes: { embedded: 'load' }
     });
   }
});
```

My solution is further explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526470/how-do-i-load-two-models-in-one-json-request-in-ember-data/13551856#13551856).

Comment: Well, it does really work. I've set up an example so you can see for yourself. Unfortunately I couldn't get it working on JSFiddle, so you can find it [here](http://olmeca.nl/rae/emberdata1/). Just check the app.js file.